# How to write hasura kubernetes deployment file to connect multiple postgres database

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, devops, hasura

Folks

I have multiple postgres db instances.

I need to create hasura deployment file to connect multiple postgres databases.

Any suggestion for creating deployment file.

Answer (score 0):

The kubernetes deployment file is right here :
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hasura/graphql-engine/stable/install-manifests/kubernetes/deployment.yaml
How to use it with multiple datasouces is explained in the v2 documentation:

- Multiple databases can be connected to Hasura for generating APIs.
- The metadata is stored in Postgres and can be configured using
  HASURA_GRAPHQL_METADATA_URL pointing to a Postgres DB. The difference
  in v2 is that, this can now be a separate Postgres DB, different from
  your application db where you create and manage your models and data.
  More information on this blog: https://hasura.io/blog/migrating-from-hasura-v1-3-to-v2-0/